# How to replace value in string using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

Here my string `($commit$ + $Bug$)/$HR$*($Leader$^$IT$)`... I want to replace all `$variable$` replace with 1...

like `(1 + 1)/1*(1^1)`...

is there possible to replace with value 1 ??? how??

Don't care which variable in  between $*_*_$...

Please Help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
\$(.*?)*\$  Or (\$\w*\$)+
preg_replace('/\$(.*?)*\$/i', '1', '($commit$ + $Bug$)/$HR$*($Leader$^$IT$)');
```

1] [Click Here](http://codepad.org/ZcSqcFyC)

2] [Better one](http://codepad.org/NvHl557l)

Check above links for answer

Comment: Sorry but check now its working now that's some string problem

Comment: @chintu: So `0` is not allowed inside the variable name? And `$$$` or `$´$` would be legal variable names? Strange...

Comment: What exact happen 

You can also try more better option here http://codepad.org/NvHl557l

Comment: Nice, edit your script to match my regex and you get the check. lol

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\$ # Match $
    \w+  # Match one or more alphanumeric characters
    \$   # Match $/x', 
    '1', $subject);
```

This assumes that only the characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]` are legal between `$` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '($commit$ + $Bug$)/$HR$*($Leader$^$IT$)';
$str = preg_replace('/\$(.*?)\$/', '1', $str);
echo $str;
```